# Are all drone propellers compatible with all brushless motors?

Tags: quadcopter, motor, brushless-motor, uav

I want to build a drone using these motors

- [SunnySky X2212 KV1400 Brushless Motor For RC Drone FPV Racing Multi Rotor](https://www.banggood.com/Wholesale-SunnySky-X2212-KV1400-Brushless-Motor-For-RC-Models-p-60577.html?cur_warehouse=CN)

and these propellers

- [DYNAM 2X RC Model Airplanes 9x5 Inch Nylon Propellers DYP-1003](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LNFHXPU)

Are all propellers compatible with all brushless motors? If not, how do I know if mine are compatible with each other?

Comment: @jsotola no, but how do I know if my propellers are compatible with my motors?

Comment: I question sometimes how one can get as far as to google and post at SE...but not enough to find the thing they're looking for....https://www.banggood.com/Racerstar-A2212-1400KV-2-4S-Brushless-Motor-For-RC-Airplane-p-1085430.html?rmmds=detail-left-hotproducts__1&cur_warehouse=CN maybe this will be helpful to understand whats required

Comment: Try this - https://www.ecalc.ch/xcoptercalc.php

Comment: Please *[be nice](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)* @morbo and for specific guidelines, see our [Code of Conduct](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: Same goes for @jsotola

Comment: That site looks like an excellent resource @HighVoltage and this would be a great basis for a comprehensive answer to this question with a little explanation of how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. It is about efficiency, agility, and maneuverability of your drone.

> Just like wheels on a car, the size of the propeller needs to be matched to the rest of the power system. For example, putting 3” props on a motor designed for 5” propellers will result in extremely high RPM and power draw and will create very little thrust. Likewise, putting large props on a small motor will likely be too much for the motor to spin, this will create very little thrust, lots of heat and excessive current draw. Extreme mismatches can damage motors and ESC’s.

The same propeller on two different motors can have vastly different performance. Even in the worst-case scenario it is possible that by a bad chose of your propeller, the drone could not take off or on the other hand, they will break when the robot is flying!

Read more at [All about Multirotor Drone FPV Propellers](https://www.getfpv.com/learn/new-to-fpv/all-about-multirotor-fpv-drone-propellers/)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* hosh0425. Thanks for your answer. We generally prefer answers to be self contained where possible, but this is a big topic, so references to external resources are fine. When linking though, please try to avoid using *here* or similar as the link text. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) and if this happens, *link* doesn't help anyone find the page. Often missing pages haven't been removed, they have just been moved to another location. If you give the page title as the link text then a search for that text will often find the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all propellors are compatible with all motors brushed or brushless if you’re looking for the right propellor for your motor.

And yes, the propellors that you’ve linked in your question will fit the motors that you’ve also linked.

Make sure you double check using the specifications of the motors and propellors, usually found on the product page of online market places, however, the amazon link doesn’t seem to have it.

Most of the time, with your propellors you’ll get small pipe things that fit around your motor shaft to make the diameter of the shaft bigger so the propellor will fit much tighter, forgot what they’re called, oops.

Comment: A bushing usually.